# Minimal DNNRegressor example with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Python and TensorFlow and I'm trying to build a simple working example with fake data in TensorFlow. My goal is to use the DNNRegressor estimator to predict a real value from a multidimensional input. This is the code I wrote:

```py
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Amount of train samples
m_train = 1000
# Amount of test samples
m_test = 100
# Dimensions for each sample
n = 10

def from_dataset(ds):
   return lambda: ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

# Create random samples with numpy
train_data = (np.random.sample((m_train,n)), np.random.sample((m_train,1)))
test_data = (np.random.sample((m_test,n)), np.random.sample((m_test,1)))

# Create two datasets, one for trainning and the other for testing
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_data)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test_data)

feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=n)]

model = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(hidden_units=[20, 20], feature_columns=feature_columns)

# Train the model
model.train(input_fn=from_dataset(train_dataset), steps=1000)

# Evaluate the unseen samples
eval_result = model.evaluate(input_fn=from_dataset(test_dataset))
```

And this is the error I get:

```
$ python fake.py 
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /tmp/tmp1j5irF
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fake.py", line 28, in <module>
    model.train(input_fn=from_dataset(train_dataset), steps=1000)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 314, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 743, in _train_model
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 725, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 448, in _model_fn
    config=config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 153, in _dnn_model_fn
    'Given type: {}'.format(type(features)))
ValueError: features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. Given type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

I supose I have to use a dictionary of Tensors, but I'm just beginning in Python and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the iterator returned by get_one(), rather than a lambda function that returns the iterator. Check out https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/examples/get_started/regression/dnn_regression.py